# How to iterate throught multiple releated tables with SQLite-Net Extensions?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying to iterate throught multiple releated tables with SQLite-Net Extensions. But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (var topTableItem in Database.GetAllWithChildren<TopTable>())
        {
            foreach (var middleTableItem in topTableItem.MiddleTableList)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.Id); // The same database entry as in the working code (see below)

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.BottomTableList.Count); // Always return 0
                foreach (var bottomTableItem in middleTableItem.BottomTableList)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("It works"); // Never reached, because middleTableItem.BottomTableList.Count == 0
                }
            }
        }
```

With "MiddleTable" as entry point, it works:

```
foreach (var middleTableItem in Database.GetAllWithChildren<MiddleTable>())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.Id); // The same database entry as in the not working example (see above)

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.BottomTableList.Count); // Return > 0
            foreach (var bottomTableItem in middleTableItem.BottomTableList)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("It works"); // Reached!
            }
        }
```

TopTable, with the list with MiddleTable Items:

```
public class TopTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<MiddleTable> MiddleTableList{ get; set; } = new List<MiddleTable>();
}
```

MiddleTable, with the list with BottomTable Items:

```
public class MiddleTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<BottomTable> BottomTableList { get; set; } = new List<BottomTable>();

    [ForeignKey(typeof(TopTable))]
    public int TopTableId{ get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public TopTable TopTable{ get; set; } = null;
}
```

BottomTable:

```
public class BottomTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";

    [ForeignKey(typeof(MiddleTable))]
    public int MiddleTableId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public MiddleTable MiddleTable { get; set; }
}
```

Before the loops I insert the objects:

```
List<BottomTable> TheList { get; set; } = new List<BottomTable>(); 

        var bottomTableObj = new BottomTable { Test = "ok" };
        Database.Insert(bottomTableObj);

        TheList.Add(bottomTableObj);

        var middleTableObj = new MiddleTable { Test = "ok", BottomTableList = TheList.ToList() };
        Database.Insert(middleTableObj);

        var middleTableListTemp = new List<MiddleTable>();
        middleTableListTemp.Add(middleTableObj);

        var topTableObj = new TopTable {Test = "ok", MiddleLableList = middleTableList.Temp.ToList()};
        Database.Insert(topTableObj);

        Database.UpdateWithChildren(topTableObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GetAllWithChildren` you are only loading the first level of relationships.

Try setting the `recursive` flag to `true`:

```
var topTableItems = Database.GetAllWithChildren<TopTable>(recursive: true)
foreach (var topTableItem in topTableItems) {
```

Or fetch the children manually in the for-loop:

```
foreach (var topTableItem in Database.GetAllWithChildren<TopTable>())
{
    foreach (var middleTableItem in topTableItem.MiddleTableList)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.Id); // The same database entry as in the working code (see below)

        // Fetch MiddleTable children            
        conn.GetChildren(middleTableItem);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(middleTableItem.BottomTableList.Count); // Always return 0
        foreach (var bottomTableItem in middleTableItem.BottomTableList)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("It works");
        }
    }
}
```